# C: undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

I'm very new to coding and I have been trying to write code to adds two integers. But whenever I try to run it using 'gcc addition.c' in the terminal I always reports an error. I tried reinstalling the compiler i.e Mingw several times but the problem does not gets fixed.
(I m currently doing C language on VS CODE software, when you answer to my issue please use layman language)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x=1;
    int y=2;
    int z=0;
    z=x+y;
    printf("%d", z);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Windows PowerShell
PS D:\C tutorials> gcc addition.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to "WinMain@16' collect.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Make sure the file is saved before running it. The error seems to imply it can't find the main function.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. Both code and terminal output. Also please take some time to Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to search for your error message? Copy-paste `undefined reference to WinMain` into your favorite search engine, and you should be getting plenty of interesting links to read about the issue.

Comment: check if Mingw bin folder path is in your environment variable

Comment: @abdoSalm If the path to the `bin` directory didn't exist already, the error would be that the `gcc` command could not be found. So the path is set up correctly.

Comment: this is question 100+ with the same problem: First **SEARCH** SO for a possible duplicate with answers.

Comment: As a beginner get used to NEVER use spaces in file names and directory names, use `_`, `-` or `.` for space

Comment: `WinMain` is the entry point for a Windows program using graphics. Your program looks like you should instead choose type Console program.

Answer (score -1):

I added a \n to clean up the printf().

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int x=1;
    int y=2;
    int z=0;
    z=x+y;
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}


% gcc -o addition addition.c -lc ; ./addition
3
```

You needed to include the C library, represented by the `-lc` in the gcc line.

Comment: Failing to link with the C library (which the `gcc` frontend program should do by default) should result in more errors, like missing the call to `printf`.

Comment: Also, adding a newline to the `printf` is rather irrelevant to the problem as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but then we get the questions that the command line is messed up